# SQL Server Join or Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know key to find how to solve my problem. Please help me.

I have 2 table as

Table A:

```
ID Item
-------
SB SanBay
VP VanPhong
```

Table B:

```
Ma HangHoa
-------
1 AAA
2 BBB
3 CCC
4 DDD
```

And i want to select to :

```
Item HangHoa
------------
SanBay AAA
SanBay BBB
SanBay CCC 
SanBay DDD
VanPhong AAA
VanPhong BBB
VanPhong CCC
VanPhong DDD
```

Thank a lots

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [cross join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join). A cross join is a simple join but with no join conditions. Thus every record in A matches every record in B.
Example:

```
Select item,hanghoa from A cross join B
```

or more simply and more commonly

```
select item,hanghoa from A,B
```

Both forms are equivalent, but the "cross join" syntax is probably a better habit because it says "yes I really did want to omit any join conditions"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below `CROSS JOIN`, A SQL `CROSS JOIN` produces a result set which is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table if no `WHERE` clause is used along with `CROSS JOIN`.This kind of result is called as Cartesian Product.

```
    select ta.Item, tb.HangHoa
    from tableA ta cross join
    tableB tb
```

Below is a link that will provide more infomation of required.

[More Info](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)